# Is it semantically correct to put images inside of a HTML list for a slideshow?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

I see HTML list used for all sorts of things all over the web and it really has me confused on how to use them semantically. It's pretty obvious that list were created to list text or link but what about images for a slideshow, something about this feels wrong?

```
<ul class="slideshow">
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/480x270" alt="Slide 1"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/480x270" alt="Slide 2"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/480x270" alt="Slide 3"></li>
</ul>
```

Is it more semantically correct to use divs like this?

```
<div class="slideshow">
  <div><img src="http://placehold.it/480x270" alt="Slide 1"></div>
  <div><img src="http://placehold.it/480x270" alt="Slide 2"></div>
  <div><img src="http://placehold.it/480x270" alt="Slide 3"></div>
</div>
```

I also have seen forms built using list, and I'm not really sure about that ether. I looked at the W3C docs and it looks like it will validate but is it semantically correct?

Comment: If it validates, it is semantically correct...

Comment: The word “semantic” has no objective meaning in contexts like this (rather paradoxical, isn’t it?), so this is an opinion poll rather than anything else. You should be more worried about the lack of `alt` attributes rather than “semantics”. (Speech-based user agents may treat `ul` differently from `div`, but they surely need the `alt` texts.)

Comment: @Jukka Hmm I guess I never really thought of semantics as opinions but I guess you are right.

Answer (score 4):

yes. actually i've seen great arguments that everything is a list and therefore listing up your comment is entirely the semantic way to go....

the ul approach is superior to the div because it gives more context than div does. not a huge difference, but noticeable and important.

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely more semantic to use a list over div elements. As long as what you're displaying is a list of 'things' then using the list element good.

Answer (score 0):

There probably isn't an issue either way until you start getting into fluid or responsive designs. Then the ul idea stops making sense.

Answer (score 0):

I think that unordered list is more semantic correct. Slideshows are lists of things displayed with different effects.

DIVs are tags with no semantic meaning, so, What would you choose?

Tip: Always fill the alt attribute for img tag.